# ver etiqueta completa ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo hacer para que las etiquetas de mis barras se vean completas (en el primer caso no se ve completa)

```
ggplot(data=derivates, aes(x=reorder(EMPRESA, Derivates),
                      y=Derivates,
                      fill=EMPRESA,
                      width=0.5,
                      label=Derivates)) +  
    coord_flip() +  
    geom_bar(stat="identity", color="white", fill="blue") + 
    geom_text(aes(label    =format(Derivates,
                                   big.mark = "'", scientific = FALSE, digits = 0.5)), 
              hjust=-0.10, 
              size =3.0) +

    xlab(NULL) + ylab (NULL)+
    ggtitle("Derivates") +   
    theme(
      axis.text.x=element_blank(),
      axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
      plot.title = element_text(color="black", size=14, face="italic"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el parámetro `ylim` de `coord_flip()` para ajustar los limites de la gráfica, y tomar como referencia el valor máximo de `x` y ajustarlo un determinado porcentaje para lograr que se vean todas las etiquetas.

Por ejemplo, para aumentar un 10%:

```
coord_flip(ylim=c(0, max(derivates$Derivates)*1.1))
```

Comment: Excelente¡, con ello ahora se ven todas las etiquetas correctamente. Intente probar con xlim(0,1) como me sugirieron pero me salia "Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale"